# What dtype to input image as according to get_input_details

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am having trouble inputting an image into [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/2) model.

Here is what get_input_details outputs

```
[{'name': 'module/hub_input/images_uint8', 'index': 170, 'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0078125, 128), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([0.0078125], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([128], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

According to the description on Tensorflow hub, it should be

> 3-channel RGB color images of size 224 x 224, scaled to [0, 1].

I have this script to accomplish this

```py
def process_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    new_image = image.resize((224,224))
    np_image = asarray(new_image)

    min = np_image.min()
    max = np_image.max()    

    # normalize to the range 0-1
    np_image = np_image.astype('float32')
    np_image -= min
    np_image /= (max - min)

    return [np_image]
```

Afterwards, I pass in the image and get this error

> ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type FLOAT32 but expected type UINT8 for input 170, name: module/hub_input/images_uint8

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is unrelated to your input image size and I believe it is because of the image type. Are you sure you should be normalizing between 0 and 1? The error seems to indicate that the input should be of type uint8. If that is the case the following code should work.

```
def process_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    new_image = image.resize((224,224))
    np_image = asarray(new_image)
    np_image = np_image.astype('uint8')

    return [np_image]
```

Comment: Hey, @DMolony. I'm upset and grateful for your clarity. I was totally overthinking and just going off of what the description said instead of taking a step back and just trying what it told me. Thanks for the help!